# How to turn off the screen after a time specified by the user?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a timer for YouTube, so when the specified by user time (in minutes) passes, the screen would turn off. My problem is that the timer is not working, so the screen is not turning off. My method to turn off the screen is to set the screen timeout to 1 second then restore the original value. The permission to change system settings and ignore battery optimization is requested. Here is my entire code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private ImageButton startbutton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startbutton = findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        startbutton.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
    }

    public void onClick(View view){
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.imageButton:
                EditText minsinput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
                int minutes = Integer.parseInt(minsinput.getText().toString());
                if (minutes<=0) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder nullvalue = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    nullvalue.setIcon(R.drawable.descarga);
                    nullvalue.setMessage("Introduce un valor.");
                    nullvalue.setTitle("Introduce un valor");
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = nullvalue.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
                if (minutes>180) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    alert.setIcon(R.drawable.descarga);
                    alert.setMessage("Debes introducir un valor más pequeño que 180.");
                    alert.setTitle("Valor fuera de rango");
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
                if (minutes<=180) {
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    boolean WriteSettingsPermission = Settings.System.canWrite(context);
                    if(!WriteSettingsPermission) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder writesettings = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                        writesettings.setIcon(R.drawable.descarga);
                        writesettings.setMessage("Esta app necesita permisos para modificar ajustes del sistema. Bajo ningún concepto se modificarán otros ajustes que no afecten al funcionamiento de la app. SIEMPRE cuando se apague la pantalla se revertirán los cambios. Además, Youtube Timer debe ser excluido de la optimización de batería. Por favor, ve a ajustes y concede el permiso y excluye de optimización a Youtube Timer.");
                        writesettings.setTitle("Alerta");
                        writesettings.setPositiveButton(
                                "ACEPTAR",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                }
                        );
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = writesettings.create();
                        alertDialog.show();
                    }
                    /*Multiply minutes per 1ms (example 90 mins * 1ms)*/
                    minutes = minutes * 1000;
                    /*Wait until time passes, then store the default value for screen time out, set it to 1 second and finally restore the original value*/
                    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            int defaultTime = 0;
                            try {
                                defaultTime = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT);
                            } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, 1000);
                            final int finalDefaultTime = defaultTime;
                            new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, finalDefaultTime);
                                }
                            }, 1000);

                        }
                    }, minutes);



                }
        }

    }


}
```

Where is the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest AlarmManager.

Answer (score 0):

welcome. Two things:

1. I recommend you use an alarm (`AlarmManager`) instead of `Timer.schedule`.
2. The way that I solved it is using `DevicePolicyManager` class and set my app as [Device Admin](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin):

   ```
   class ScreenActions(val context:Context) {

    private var componentName: ComponentName
    private var devicePolicyManager: DevicePolicyManager

    init {
        componentName = ComponentName(context, DeviceAdmin::class.java)
        devicePolicyManager = context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE) as DevicePolicyManager
    }

    fun isDeviceAdmin() = devicePolicyManager.isAdminActive(componentName)

    fun turnOffScreen() = devicePolicyManager.lockNow()
   }
   ```

Sorry for Kotlin code, I think that it is understandable.